# need starting point on drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm learning jQuery and need advice/help on the creation of a drop down menu. So far I have it set up where I scroll down and the links disappear and a link called "menu" appears.

I would like to know how to have the links slide down when I click on the menu.. I'm not too sure how to go about doing this.

Here's what I have so far

html

```
<div class="container">

    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">
            <span class="menu">Menu</span>
            </a>

            <ul>
                <li>link1</li>
                <li>link2</li>
                <li>link3</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="blueDiv">
    </div>

    <div class="redDiv">
    </div>

    <div class="greenDiv">
    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var topScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (topScroll >= 3) {
        $(".menu").show();
        $("ul").hide();
    } else{
        $("span").hide();
        $("ul").show();
    }
})


$("a").click(function(){
    $("nav.ul").slideToggle();
})
```

I don't mind list of easy to use plug-ins as well.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you first mention a drop-down menu, but you seem to be trying to create a menu that only appears when you scroll down the page rather than hovering over it. Can you please clarify or provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to this demo http://codepen.io/engza/pen/ukLgy            

So when you scroll, the links disappear and replaced with a three bar menu icon.

Comment: I have a jsfiddle but the javascript is not working on there. I can post it for a better explanation if I'm still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, here's a [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/3Eh3P/) that expands on the example you provided from CodePen.

All you needed to add was:

```
 $(document).scroll(function(){
    $('.navigation').hide();
 })
```

So now your script hides the menu when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $('.navigation').hide();
```

Then toggles it on or off when the user clicks it.

```
   $('.box').click(function(){  
      $('.navigation').toggle();  
      });  
  });
```

Lastly, it hides the menu when the user scrolls.

```
 $(document).scroll(function(){
    $('.navigation').hide();
 })
```

If you want to snaz it up a bit, you could use `slideToggle` instead of `toggle` to hide and reveal the menu :)

Comment: Thanks. So I had it right, but I guess it looked like a glitch the way I had it set up.

Comment: I want the navigation to slide down from under the menu floated at the right. 

To achieve this, would I create a new navigation and keep it hidden until the menu button is clicked? Or would I keep the existing menu and use jQuery and/or CSS to position it to the right?

Comment: I'd use CSS for the positioning. If HTML and CSS can do the job, no point in slowing your page with Javascript doing it instead. CSS animations will also render more smoothly than JS.